# Match object in list of tuples to object in dataframe, create new column if match exists

Tags: python, string, pandas, tuples

Consider the following list of tuples:

```
some_strings = [('Name1', 'ABCD', 'DEFG', 'Score=12'),
                ('Name2', 'JKLL', 'RMPQ', 'Score=11')]
```

And the following pandas dataframe:

```
Sequence ID    Left Sequence    Right Sequence
Name1              ABCD             RQLM
Name1              ABCR             PLMT
Name2              JKLL             ZFGQ
Name2              RPLP             FTRD
```

I am trying to compare the second object in the tuple to the column df['Left Sequence'] to check for an exact match (not concerned with partial matches), and if the match occurs, print dimer in a new column at the end of the df. If a match does not occur, I will print NA. Here is the code I have tried:

```
for x in some_strings:
    for y in x:
        df['Dimers'] = df['Left Sequence'].apply(lambda s: 'Dimer' if s == y[1] else 'NA')
```

My expected output:

```
Sequence ID    Left Sequence    Right Sequence    Dimers
Name1              ABCD             RQLM          Dimer
Name1              ABCR             PLMT           NA
Name2              JKLL             ZFGQ          Dimer
Name2              RPLP             FTRD           NA
```

My actual output (you can probably guess this):

```
Sequence ID    Left Sequence    Right Sequence    Dimers
Name1              ABCD             RQLM           NA
Name1              ABCR             PLMT           NA
Name2              JKLL             ZFGQ           NA
Name2              RPLP             FTRD           NA
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create mask of Boolean : we using `isin` to create the mask

```
mask=df.iloc[:,:-1].apply(tuple,1).isin([x[:-2] for x in some_strings])    
df['Dimer']='NA'
df.loc[mask,'Dimer']='Dimer'        
df
Out[1120]: 
  SequenceID LeftSequence RightSequence  Dimer
0      Name1         ABCD          RQLM  Dimer
1      Name1         ABCR          PLMT     NA
2      Name2         JKLL          ZFGQ  Dimer
3      Name2         RPLP          FTRD     NA
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working for my practice dataset, but the mask is returning false for my real dataset, so there must be some underlying issue. I appreciate the help!